# Is there any way to run MS OUTLOOK 2007 on LINUX?

Tags: linux, microsoft-outlook

I currently have Microsoft Business Productivity Online Suite (BPOS). It runs well with Microsoft Products like OUTLOOK (WIN) and ENTOURAGE (MAC). Unfortunately, my Linux users are struggling to run Microsoft Exchange on both Thunderbird and Evolution E-mail Clients. Is there any way to run MS OUTLOOK 2007 on LINUX? CodeWeaver CrossOver seemed to not have worked for me. May I be doing something wrong?

Comment: why does Evolution not work?

Answer (score 2):

Run a Windows instance in a VMware or VirtualBox installation.

This sort of defeats the purpose of running Linux in some ways, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Wine is usually the best bet, however even that seems not to work -

Outlook 2003 - http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iVersionId=2526

Outlook 2007 - http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=7533

I guess that there is something in it that just does not want to work on Linux!

I looked at some other methods (including the ones you listed) but it just does not seem to want to work.

Whilst it is a annoying work around, your best bet will most likely be to use virtualisation and run outlook that way. Alternatively, as you state Exchange you most likely have a server infrastructure. If there are not too many users, you may want to try installing outlook on the server and using it as a terminal server.

Again - these are just work arounds, and probably annoying at that, but they should do the job.

Sorry I cannot be more helpful, but from my research for you, it just does not seem as if Outlook wants to run on Linux.

Instead, what you may want to do is post your problems using Thunderbird or Evolution as there may be someone that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

CrossoverOffice will run Outlook